# Extract method Names of Array of Classes into Type Union

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an Array of Classes and want to extract all of their methods into one type Union.

For example:

```
class A{
  getBooks(): Book[]{}
  getBook(): Book{}
}

class B{
  getUsers(): User[]{}
  getUser(): User{}
  getBooksOfUser(userId: string)Book[]{}
}
```

I would like to have one type which has all Methods like this:

```
type allMethods = "getBooks" | "getBook" | "getUsers" | "getUser" | "getBooksOfUser";
```

I tried a few different Things but couldn't get it working:

```
const testResolvers = <const> [A, B]
type ExtractFunctionKeys<T> = { [P in keyof T]-?: T[P] extends Function ? P : never}[keyof T]
export type ValuesOf<T extends any[]>= ExtractFunctionKeys<T[number]>;

type Foo = ValuesOf<typeof testResolvers>;
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 main issues in the above attempt:

1. `T[number]` ([indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)) produces an *union* of every type in the `T` tuple/array; TypeScript [keeps only the *intersection* of keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types) (shared keys) as valid when using a variable that is a such union; in your case, `A | B` has no common key, so `keyof (A | B)` is already `never` (i.e. even without filtering for methods)
2. `typeof testResolvers` is `readonly [typeof A, typeof B]`, i.e. it distributes the `typeof` operator to the tuple elements, and we get the type of the class *constructor* instead of the actual class types; then when accessing their keys (with `keyof typeof A` for example), all we get is `"prototype"`

Issue 1: instead of a *union*, we want an *intersection*, for which TypeScript keeps the *union* of keys (all keys in any element of the intersection) as valid. There is no easy way to build such an intersection from a tuple (we cannot use the indexed access notation). But it is still do-able, e.g.:

```
// Convert a tuple into an intersection of every type in the tuple
type TupleToIntersection<T> =
    T extends readonly never[]
    ? unknown : (
        T extends readonly [infer First, ...infer Rest]
        ? First & TupleToIntersection<Rest>
        : never)

type intersection = TupleToIntersection<typeof testResolvers>
//   ^? type intersection = typeof A & typeof B
```

Issue 2: to get back the *class* type from its constructor type, we just need to make sure to access the `"prototype"` property, typically via indexed access again. We can even build a helper type to perform the conversion conditionally if necessary:

```
// Get the class (prototype) from its constructor, if available
type ConstructorToPrototype<C> = C extends { prototype: infer P } ? P : C

type AClass = ConstructorToPrototype<typeof A>
//   ^? type AClass = A
```

Then we can insert these helper types into the chain to get the desired behaviour of extracting the union of methods of all classes in the tuple:

```
// 1. Convert the tuple type into an intersection
// 2. Get the classes instead of constructor types
// 3. Get the keys which have function values (i.e. methods)
type ValuesOf<T extends readonly unknown[]> = ExtractFunctionKeys<ConstructorToPrototype<TupleToIntersection<T>>>;

type Foo = ValuesOf<typeof testResolvers>;
//   ^? type Foo = "getBooks" | "getBook" | "getUsers" | "getUser" | "getBooksOfUser"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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-AzsUjY0Ow8MONAUonBukwpkR5PI3b0V3HH6UW5Ed4SAB6MrecSgAHEtFJ8VBuHwBHowAQ4ODkwYoMM+9goIxgAJrnNMHC4ARnowUTwTjxGLxcCCSWQvjcCLPwQRqQAFPsDrEXD7stAfHl8gVWXv9-tY+TO5THlxQOWf+QfJOkoIHyRAIN5bDOc5HnAp7PsmFyFiigiVtWUB1gBZAAKK8gQPBwpaCr5ugADSEAgJQrLXlYpifswUCIKRRZkuYAC0MryGS1GWLq94CPh6CEd+UC-hgkrKM4pj0SAjGvFWjYAIz2p83yEH8eIEoGmJkGCEI8FCuYMmmzKyVAABMiktqp7advwMjjjcRpTEiKLTgwB7zppMjGQAzOZrZqXRpECCquKMBwuJQLiK7QMMBHplAq5cJgtl6Iw9oQIp2BaLicAComyZQAAajwiUyCMrJ3vqD5CiK6BivKirKmqFiUVhDC4cAfGESRZGXuBrmQSeZ4vpArKBjmqaERRty3AA3Oh0CWggtBFSVQzDPBWJFtIJZHKcJSzcZtb1kAA)

Comment: Bth, you can rewrite `TupleToIntersection type`. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/mp8Apm)

Comment: Nice usage of contravariance!